# Laravel - count records from many tables

Tags: database, laravel

Is it possible in Laravel create one query which separate count all records from 3 different not related tables? And without using Eloquent.

Example:
I have three tables, A, B, C.
I can make three separate query's that will count all records in every table.
Like "DB::table('A')->count();"

But I need a one query to do this.
$all = DB:: ??

And as a result of this variable I will get something like:

```
$all->A 
$all->B
$all->C
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just write the raw query:

```
$result = DB::select("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A) as a, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B) as b, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM C) as c");
```

Then the counts would be at `$result->a`, `$result->b`, `$result->c`